# Having trouble with Knockout.js mapping with JSON in jQM app

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, jsonp, knockout-mapping-plugin

Ok I've given up trying to hack at it, please help community:

I'm trying to map a JSONP response from the server to populate this HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: featConfirm.confirmPages -->
    <div data-role="page" class="featConfirm" data-bind="template: {name: 'featConfirm_tmp'}, attr: {'id': featConfirm.assignPageID($data.position), 'pos': $data.position}" ></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/html" id="featConfirm_tmp">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="header"><img class="owner-image" src="img/filler.jpg" />
            Did <span class="owner-name" data-bind="text: featConfirm.featOwner.full_name"></span>
        </div>   
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the js setup -  this is my best guess so far but obviously it does not work however it does create the proper number of pages with id's, however, I can't access any data from elsewhere in the JSON array:

```
function master(){
    var self = this;
    self.featConfirm = new function(){
        var self = this;
        /* KO observable used to populate view */
        self.confirmPages = ko.observableArray([]);
        /* AJAX call to server to get confirmable feats */
        self.getFeatsForConfirm = function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: sourcesURL + 'myPHP.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                                success: function(bData, textStatus, jqXHR){

                                /* this is my best guess so far but obviously it does not work however it does create the proper number of pages with id's I can't access any data from elsewhere in the JSON array */
                                for (i=0;i<bData.length;i++){
                                    var a = {position: i+1, data: ko.mapping.fromJSON(bData[i])};
                                    self.confirmPages.push(a);
                                    }
                                    },
                                error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                    console.log('There was an error submitting your request');
                                    }
                                });
            };
        }
    }
/* init Knockout */ 
ko.applyBindings(master());
```

my JSON comes in like this:

```
([
  {
    "featDetails":{"attempt":"39","owner":"2"},
    "featSpecs":{"id":"1347387875","name":"Eat a tomato"},
    "featOwner":{"full_name":"Darth Freakin Vader"}
  },
  {
    "featDetails":{"attempt":"44","owner":"1"},
    "featSpecs":{"id":"1352986771","name":"Drink Coffee"},
    "featOwner":{"full_name":"Luke Sywalker"}
  }
])
```

I've obviously fundamentally misunderstood how the mapping plugin works, which is why I've turned to you.  I've stripped **ALOT** of values from each array of the JSON data which is why I want to use the plugin, but this is the basic structure.

- Is is possible to map JSONP with the mapping plug in in this way,
- What am I not getting here,
- How would I go about mapping this data properly so I can access it in the HTML.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use JSONP with the mapping plugin (KO and the mapping plugin don't care where the data is coming from). The main issue with your code seems to be that you're not paying attention to the nesting of the KO scopes/binding-contexts.

The `foreach` creates a nested scope for each item (the context item will just be the current item in the array), so referencing `featConfirm` in the nested context doesn't make sense - you need to either reference a parent/root binding with $parent/$root (e.g. `$root.featConfirm.assignPageID`) or reference things that are actually in the nested scope (e.g. `featOwner.full_name` instead of `featConfirm.featOwner.full_name`).

For the template binding, you didn't specify any `data` so it didn't create a nested scope, but since you're creating that object wrapping the data (`var a`), you'll probably want to specify `data` for the template binding: `data-bind="template: {name: 'featConfirm_tmp', data: $data.data}` which will create another nested scope.

Finally, since you're iterating bData in the success callback, and this is a JS object (jQuery already parsed the JSON for you), you'll want to use `fromJS` instead of `fromJSON`.

Here's a working jsfiddle with these changes in place (I changed the ajax a bit to mock a server response with jsfiddle, but your ajax options for jsonp were fine): http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/592q9/3/

Comment: Bless you sir, the using fromJS instead of fromJSON is what did it for me,  if I had thought of that I might have found the answer on my own...your answer was most helpful and helped me better understand the mechanics of this. My heartfelt thanks sir, you have vanquished ignorance today.